# Xcode 6 iAd Layout Issue or Bug

Tags: autolayout, iad

I have added an iAd banner view to my project and pinned it to the top of the main view controller in a storyboard. Initially when the app loads the iAd banner is displayed at the bottom of the screen. The banner is then hidden during a game and then unhidden at the end of the game. When the banner is unhidden it appears correctly as designed in the storyboard at the top of the view. Any thoughts why this is happening? This occurs on both the simulator and real devices.

Comment: Are you using `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` in addition to creating your `ADBannerView` yourself?

Comment: Yes, I have self.canDisplayBannerAds = true located in the viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created two `ADBannerView`'s in your application. Once with `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` and once programmatically.

`self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` can be used for a *no hassle* way of implementing iAds in your application. This will create an `ADBannerView` for you and show or hide the `ADBannerView` depending on whether it receives an ad or not from the iAd network. The `ADBannerView` you're seeing at the bottom of your screen is created by `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`. The `ADBannerView` you're seeing at the top of your screen is the `ADBannerView` you have created.

Remove `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` from your `viewDidLoad` function.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, your answer has solved my problem and I guess it does seem obvious now, but all the tutorials I watched included this line even when adding a banner view via Interface Builder. Thanks again.